# Strategy for after finished attacks and no shield

Tags: clash-of-clans

Say you just attacked a base and used up your army and have no more guard left. You want to take a break from the game. What strategies are there for minimizing the resources lost when your base gets raided?

One strategy is to fill up your queue with dragons and spells and refund them after you've been attacked. The problem with this is 1) no one might attack in the time it takes to make a dragon and even if you reset it then you've wasted time when you could've been building an army you actually wanted to use 2) if you forget then you end up with a bunch of dragons and IMHO they aren't cost effective

Another strategy is to keep making an army that you actually would use as soon as your last one is used. Since I'm trying to go for cost effective armies, this doesn't always save the most resources.

Any other ideas?

Comment: What league are you in?

Comment: @Dragonrage Gold 1

Comment: townhall level?

Comment: @Dragonrage TH 8

Comment: hope that helps. sorry for the delay, was playing a game

Comment: You might be interested in this article - http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/6-tips-to-avoid-raiders-in-clash-of-clans/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [a whole article on this subject](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/6-tips-to-avoid-raiders-in-clash-of-clans/) as it's something that every CoC player struggles with.

I'll summarize my tips as best I can (the article is far too long for an answer, unfortunately.)

- Empty your collectors periodically.  Full collectors == easy raid.  Goes double for DE drills, which constitute the majority of available DE in a maxed out, full to the brim base.
- Distribute your storages AND collectors.  If I only have to destroy a third of your base to get to the loot, I'm raiding that like it's hot.
- Make the enemy destroy a lot of your worthless buildings.  Shields only kick in at certain percentages of destruction + troop deployment, so make them work for it!

There's also the TH attack penalty to consider, which means you should upgrade your town hall last.  And you've already covered what we (used to) call the "[wall breaker elixir bank](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/top-10-best-kept-secrets-in-clash-of-clans/)" (see #2) - overtraining can save a bit of your resources, although it's not terribly significant in the grand scheme of things.

As always, resources are safest when spent.  Try to focus your raids and builders so that you can keep as little on hand as possible.  This isn't always something that can be done, but ideally you're not maxing out your gold, elixir, and DE storages all at once.  Building walls, training expensive troops, upgrading your BK - all these tend to be pretty cheap ways to drain overfilled storages.

Answer (score 2):

With the changes to the shields, it is no longer a valid strategy to put your townhall in the corner to provide a free shield. This was one of the main strategies to protect loot.

Now, it is fairly likely that you will be hit by a big raid and lose quite a bit of loot every time your attacked. To help prevent this, one technique is to spread out your storages throughout your base. Don't group them all up in the middle, because if some one gets in to that compartment, you will lose it all.

Another strategy is to make it easier to get 1 star on your base, and leave some loot in your collectors. This may help people who are raiding with weaker troops to hit you for the easy star and loot, while protecting the majority of the loot.

Also queueing troops and spells will help "hide" your loot, but if you want to train an army to use in case you dont get attacked soon, you can put the troop composition for your army queued up first, and then top off the queues with more expensive troops to hide some loot. This will give both the benefit of protecting some loot, and making it easier to attack again if you dont get attacked.

Comment: In your last paragraph you seem to imply you don't fill the entire camp with troops and you don't raid with a full army, is this true? What kind of raid do you do? Do you not try to get 3 stars?

Comment: @Celeritas i was talking about the queues in the barracks. with max barracks, you can fit more troops in the queues than you can in your camps. also, as far as my raids i do giwiwi. i generally just go for the 2 star and as much of the loot as i can. i get 70% i get max loot bonus. also im in masters 2

Comment: Filling The queues Has A Major Problem, You Can Hide Your Dark Elixir And Elixir By This Technique , But You Can't Hide one Bit Of All That Gold You Have Stored , So I suggest putting the gold Storages in a more Protected Area of Your Base While Using This Method ,since gold is more useful because of it being used to level up the walls and defenses. I Never Thought of this Method , It is Good , if i can protect my Gold I Might Use it , i have a suggestion for this Method:

Comment: @Hitman2847 there is no perfect way to protect all of your loot, these are just some tips to helping save some of it. but that is a point i hadnt thought about. putting your gold in further may help protect it some of the time, but if they get to the middle it may lead to them getting more as it wont be as spread out

Comment: Use Pekka to save the elixir u have as it is more expensive than dragons And Also Takes more time to Make One (in Compare with Dragon)

Comment: and as for dark elixir the best option is using Golem , but this also Has Another Flaw , U can Ultimately Train a limited amount of troops , So as @Dragonrage said There Is No Longer A perfect Way to Do this As Some-Time Ago We Would Leave the Town Hall Outside , so Practically The Game Is Doomed After The Latest Update :(  :|